# Pagination in DRF gives "'list' object is not callable"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pagination

Using Django Rest Framework I'm trying to expose a read-only endpoint. Unfortunately I get an error which (if I read it correctly) relates to the pagination.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 40, in list
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 169, in paginate_queryset
    if self.paginator is None:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 162, in paginator
    self._paginator = self.pagination_class()

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/v1/machines/
Exception Value: 'list' object is not callable
```

I've got no pagination set up for this viewset though. My serializer looks like this:

```
class MachineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Machine
        fields = '__all__'
```

my viewset like this:

```
class MachineDataViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Machine.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MachineSerializer
```

and in my setting I've got my pagination class set up like this:

```
DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS=('rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',),
```

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found it. It should be a string, not a tuple:

```
DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS='rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with a default paginator in `djangorestframework`, the REST API configurations should be:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 50,
}
```

Where `PAGE_SIZE` is an arbitrary integer.

NOTE: The default pagination class is singular, so only one default can be specified unlike `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`, `DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES`, and `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS` which can take a `list`.

See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#setting-the-pagination-style

Answer (score 0):

I use the snippet codes below to solve the same issue, for sure it will also work for you.

```
class LargeResultsSetPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 5`
```

```
class PostListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination`
```